# Image Resizing Bilinear Interpolation and Nearest Neighbour

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing, graphics

I am currently having problems coming up with an algorithm for re-scaling and image.
I currently want to implement both Bilinear interpolation and Nearest Neighbour. I understand how both of them work conceptually but, I can not seem to record it into code. That I am still stuck on Nearest Neighbour 
I have wrote some pseudo-code for it below (based on what I know):

```
    Resizing Images: Nearest Neighbour
    Use a loop:for j=0 to Yb-1
    for i=0 to Xb-1
    for c=0 to 2
   (floor) y=j*Ya/Yb 
   (floor) x=i*Xa/Xb
    Ib[j][i][c] = Ia[y][x][c]
```

My original data set (where I get my volume of data) is stored in a 3D array with [x][y][z] with (x, y, z).I read each pixel separately and can calculate the colors for each pixel using Color.color in java. I however, need to know how I can get the color (c = [0,1,2] ) for each pixel position x and y (x,y) excluding z(for one view's) to convert 1 old pixel for each new pixel into my new data set containing the new width and Height. I have written most of the code I have translated above in Java. But I still can not understand how to finalise a working implementation.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

I am not very familiar with java. But here is a working code for python.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("image.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

scaleX = 0.5
scaleY = 0.5

newImg = np.zeros((int(img.shape[0]*scaleX),int(img.shape[1]*scaleY))).astype(np.uint8)

for y in range(newImg.shape[0]):
    for x in range(newImg.shape[1]):
        samplex = x/scaleX
        sampley = y/scaleY
        dx = samplex - np.floor(samplex)
        dy = sampley - np.floor(sampley)

        val = img[int(sampley-dy),int(samplex-dx)]*(1-dx)*(1-dy)
        val += img[int(sampley + 1 - dy),int(samplex-dx)]*(1-dx)*(dy) 
        val += img[int(sampley-dy),int(samplex + 1 - dx)]*(dx)*(1-dy)
        val += img[int(sampley + 1 -dy),int(samplex + 1 - dx)]*(dx)*(dy)

        newImg[y,x] = val.astype(np.uint8)


cv2.imshow("img",newImg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You could simply add one more for loop inside they for and x for loops to account for channels.

Answer (score 1):

if I get it right you are interpolating volumes (voxels) instead of pixels in such case:
Lets have source volume `vol1[xs1][ys1][zs1]` and target `vol0[xs0][ys0][zs0]` where `xs,ys,zs` are the resolutions then nearest neighbor would be:

```cpp
// vol0 <- vol1
for (              x0=0; x0<xs0; x0++)
 for (x1=(x*x1)/x0, y0=0; y0<ys0; y0++)
  for (y1=(y*y1)/y0, z0=0; z0<zs0; z0++)
   {    z1=(z*z1)/z0;
   vol0[x0][y0][z0]=vol1[x1][y1][z1];
   }
```

The color stays the same for nearest neighbor. In case `vol0` has smaller resolutions than `vol1` you can do the `for` loops at `vol1` resolution and compute `x0,y0,z0` from `x1,y1,z1` instead to speed up. Btw. all the variables are integers no floats needed for this...

Now for the color encoding in case your voxels are 1D array (`{r,g,b}`) instead of scalar integral type:

```cpp
vol0[xs0][ys0][zs0][3] 
vol1[xs1][ys1][zs1][3]
```

the stuff would change to:

```cpp
// vol0 <- vol1
for (              x0=0; x0<xs0; x0++)
 for (x1=(x*x1)/x0, y0=0; y0<ys0; y0++)
  for (y1=(y*y1)/y0, z0=0; z0<zs0; z0++)
   for (z1=(z*z1)/z0; i=0;  i<3;    i++ )
    vol0[x0][y0][z0][i]=vol1[x1][y1][z1][i];
```

Comment: They are pixels. I have an array of three dimensions that stores each pixel based on there x,y and z positions. so instead of volumes it's image[][][]

Comment: @BrevynKurt such data is called volumetric and the individual 3D cells holding color are called voxels instead of pixels... to distinguish 3D from 2D ...